# char search in a string

Tags: c, while-loop

Can anybody help me with my code

```
int main(void){

    int ctr,wordLength;

    char theWord[99];

    ctr = 0;

    printf("Enter a Word: ");
    scanf("%s", & );
    printf("Enter the letter you want to find: ");
    scanf("%s", & );

    while(ctr < wordLength | theWord[ctr]=='a'){

ctr++;
    }

//output
}
```

expecting output

Enter a Word: hello

Enter the letter you want to find: z

the letter z is not found in the word.

Comment: What do you mean by `scanf("%s", & );`???

Comment: i leave it blank i dont know what should i input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can do it this way also,

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main(void)
  {
     int ctr;
     char theWord[99], ch;
     ctr = 0;
     printf("Enter a Word: ");
     scanf("%s", theWord);
     printf("Enter the letter you want to find: ");
     scanf(" %c", &ch );

    for(int i = 0; theWord[i]; i++)
    {
       if(theWord[i] == ch)
          ctr++;
    }
    if(ctr != 0)
       printf("word is found\n");
    else
       printf("word is not found\n");
  }
  ```
- Yes, we can do it it using while loop also,

  ```
  int i = 0;
  while(theWord[i] != '\0' )
  {
     if(theWord[i] == ch)
       ctr++;
       i++;
  }
  if(ctr != 0)
     printf("word is found\n");
  else
     printf("word is not found\n");
  ```

Comment: Good proposal.  You might want to protect the entry with `scanf("%98s", theWord);` and test the return values from `scanf`.

Comment: And you can also save one variable, and simplify the code by not counting the chars (just display + return if found)

Comment: @chqrlie Actually it seems they have to use a *while* loop (it's a *for* btw) according to the title

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code

```
int main (void)
{
    int ctr = 0;
    int wordLength;
    char theWord[99], ch;

    printf("Enter a Word: ");
    scanf("%s", theWord);

    printf("Enter the letter you want to find: ");
    scanf("%c", &ch);

    while (theWord [ctr] != '\0')
    {
        if (theWord [ctr] == ch)
        {
            print("Character found at position %1", ctr);
            break;
        }
        ctr++;
    }
    if (theWord [ctr] == '\0')
    {
        printf ("Character not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: This will most likely search for `'\n'`.  Use `scanf(" %c", &ch);` to ignore the pending `\n`.

Answer (score -1):

I did correction of your code, It works successfully with GCC

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){

    int ctr = 0,c = 0, wordLength;

    char ch, theWord[99];

    printf("Enter a Word: ");
    scanf("%s", theWord);
    printf("Enter the letter you want to find: ");
    scanf("%c", & ch);

    wordLength = strlen(theWord);

    while(theWord[ctr] != '\0')
    {
        if (theWord[ctr] == ch)
        {
            printf("the letter %c is found in the word\n", ch);
            c++;
        }
        ctr++;
    }
        if (c == 0 )
        {
         printf("the letter %c is NOT found in the word\n", ch);
        }
}
```

Comment: scanf("%s", & ch);?

c++;

?

Comment: this is not string search.. Even if it is, your code is incorrect

Comment: @ninja Sorry it is my mistake.

Comment: by the way...if i enter letter p it display 2 times as the word is apple

Comment: Did you really test your program?  It always fails on my environment because the character read is the pending `\n`.

Comment: @msc: it successfully compiles and executes, but does it find `e` in `hello`?

Comment: @KnetJhonCarino: the code iterates for each character in `theWord` until it reaches the `'\0'` that terminates the C string.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes it is find 'e' in "hello".

Comment: @msc: I cast a spell of disbelieve! Either you did not copy the code correctly to post it or your C library is buggy, which is unlikely. What environment do you use?

Comment: @chqrlie GCC compiler

Comment: @msc: you already specified the name of the compiler twice, are you using Windows, MinGW, cygwin, linux, MacOS...

Comment: @chqrlie Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: @msc: It does not work on Ubuntu, it won't even let me type the letter: `~/dev/stackoverflow$ ./scanc
Enter a Word: hello
Enter the letter you want to find: the letter
 is NOT found in the word
~/dev/stackoverflow$`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102062/discussion-between-msc-and-chqrlie).